# Using rownum with the combination of between keyword

Tags: oracle

I have seen this Oracle SQL  query for using rownum with the combination of  between keyword .

```
select *
from
( select rownum rnum, a.*
from (your_query) a
where rownum <= :M )
where rnum >= :N;
```

in order to get rows n through m from 'your query.'

I want to try it , Could anybody please tell me how can i get the data from an Emp table to fetch records from 4 to 8 Records

```
select *
from
( select rownum rnum, a.*
from (select * from emp) a
where rownum <= 4 )
where rnum >= 8;
```

But this isn't working , could anybody please tell me why .

Thank you very much .

Comment: Swap your rownum values...(EDIT: diagonalbatman got there first :-))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I had to guess, I'd say that the reason you're not seeing what you expect (in addition to having the operators backwards, as pointed out by @diagonalbatman) is that you didn't tell the database what order you wanted the rows in. You're essentially telling the database to return any 5 rows. You can't even be sure that this query will always return the same five rows. Any time you're getting a subset like this, you should use an `order by` clause in the innermost query, so that the sort is applied before the `rownum` values are issued:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT ROWNUM rnum, a.*
        FROM   (SELECT   *
                FROM     emp
                ORDER BY emp_id) a
        WHERE  ROWNUM <= 8)
WHERE  rnum >= 4;
```

Answer (score 4):

This is because you are limiting your query to <=4 rows, so when you filter to show records >=8 there are only 4 records to look at....

Invert the numbers and you should see a result:

```
select *
from
( select rownum rnum, a.*
from (select * from emp) a
where rownum <= 8 )
where rnum >= 4;
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are querying the whole data in the inner statement (if you have huge data amounds, no good idea!) you could as well use the BETWEEN keyword.

```
SELECT *
  FROM 
       (SELECT rownum AS rnum,
               a.* 
          FROM EMP) a
 WHERE rnum BETWEEN 4 AND 8;
```

Comment: Right, just saving some chars ;-)

Comment: Not just that - its more efficient too

Comment: @diagonalbatman: This version is not more efficient. Your solution can use a `count stopkey` to get only the rows below the upper bound before applying the lower bound. This version will get `rownum` for the entire table before applying the filter. The only exception is if the innermost query is sorted on an un-indexed column, in which case both queries perform roughly equivalently, since they both have to sort the entire table first anyhow.